# Calling Python code within Haskell

Tags: python, haskell

I have a bunch (or will have a bunch) of Python code that uses the OpenCV libraries, as well as SimpleCV. I also have a bunch of Haskell code that does some other stuff, but wants to call one function that I define in the Python. This one function returns a three-tuple of doubles.

What's the best way to go about calling this function in Haskell?

For instance, a simplified case is if I have a function in Python

```
# foo.py
import SimpleCV

def foo():
   return (1.0,2.0,3.0)
```

I want to be able to do this in Haskell

```
-- bar.hs

main = do
  putStrLn $ show pyThingy.foo
```

I've tried using MissingPy (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingPy), but whenever I try to import the local file I just get

```
*** Exception: <<MissingPy.Python.Types.PyException>>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/). It's for scalable cross-language services development, combines a software stack with a code generation engine to build services that work efficiently and seamlessly between C++, Java, **Python**, PHP, Ruby, Erlang, Perl, **Haskell**, C#, Cocoa, JavaScript, Node.js, Smalltalk, OCaml and Delphi and other languages.

Comment: Works perfectly - had to wrestle with it a little bit (stupid broken packages on my system T_T) but now it works! Hooray!